# 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.intents.list' on 'projects/None/agent' denied

Tags: dialogflow-es

```
import os
from fastapi import Request
from dotenv import load_dotenv
project_id = os.getenv('project_id')
import google.cloud.dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow


intents_client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()
parent = dialogflow.AgentsClient.agent_path(project_id)
```

I am trying to get the "intent list" / "entity list" but dialogflow does not response instead this message was showed

"403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.intents.list' on 'projects/None/agent' denied"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can not use the dialogflow api in the local host. You will need to make it live with ngrok and then this will work. It will give all sorts of error on the local host.